# architectural patterns for server applications

Tags: web, architecture, client

I have a bit of a dilemma here, I'll try to be specific.

I am working on my development stack for web applications, but I am a little unclear on how to architecture the server side. I have worked this matter before, but mostly it has been disorganized and unmaintainable code. I tend to keep the stuff that happens in the client separated from the stuff that happens on the server, meaning that the code on the server does not respond to events triggered by - nor influences the user interface, but instead it responds to requests made by the client application (a bit like a RESTful api).

As an example, think of a notes-taking web application where the server handles the user authentication requested by the client and online storage; while the client handles user interaction (DOM manipulation and responding to events), offline storage, syncing the notes to the server and other offline functionality.

My question is, what (server side) architectural patterns should I consider when developing these systems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are not design patterns, but *architectural patterns*. And even those patterns have to be decided from case to case. It's a bad idea to set one of those patterns as a *standard*, since none of those patterns can be regarded to as a *standard*.

On the other hand Design patterns help you with even more specific problems.

**some words to MVC:**
normally on webapplications your View and control are client based. While your model rests on the client AND on the server side. So on your server side you have neither a Control, nor a View anyway. The only decision that needs to be made, is how to synchronize the two halfs of your model.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think I might have used the wrong words then; when I said that I was working on a set of standards, I meant that I am working on my development stack, but I am a bit unclear on how I will architecture the server side.  

About the MVC, even though that makes sense and that is what I am trying to achieve, many web apps are not designed that way in the sense that much of its user interaction and behaviour runs on the server, i.e. php.

Comment: I will edit the question, but I would appreciate if you could expand a bit on the topic about architectural patterns. -Cheers